# What is this C syntax #define GET_UINT32_BE(n,b,i)?

Tags: c++, c

```
#define GET_UINT32_BE(n,b,i)                            \
{                                                       \
   (n) = ( (uint32_t) (b)[(i)    ] << 24 )              \
      | ( (uint32_t) (b)[(i) + 1] << 16 )              \
      | ( (uint32_t) (b)[(i) + 2] <<  8 )              \
      | ( (uint32_t) (b)[(i) + 3]       );             \
}
```

What does it do? and what are these `\` characters

Comment: the ``\`` is escaping the line breaks, to force the parser/compiler to treat the entire block as a single line.

Comment: On a side note, this would be much better as a `constexpr` function.

Comment: this code is pretty dangerous as it rely on type of `b` being a single byte type like `char *`.

Comment: This would be even much better as an expression that just returns the computed value.

Comment: @user3528438 Further danger: `b` being a _unsigned_ single byte type like `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a preprocessor macro definition.

The backslash means that the line is to be continued on the next physical line.

The macro is probably intended to be used like this:

```
const uint8_t bytes[] = { 0xfe, 0xed, 0xf0, 0x0d };
uint32_t x;

GET_UINT32_BE(x, bytes, 0);
```

This will set `x` to `0xfeedf00d`. Not sure why it's written as a braced scope, doesn't seem to add any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This converts a 32-bit number in big-endian memory layout to native internal representation. Google "endian".

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered it is a multiline macro to convert between big and little endian format.

There are two different ways of storing data in memory. Big and little endian. The difference is whether the most significant byte of a data type is at lowest or highest address.

Example:
uint32_t t = 0x12345678;

Little endian memory:

```
addr N+0: 0x78 
addr N+1: 0x56 
addr N+2: 0x34 
addr N+3: 0x12
```

Big endian memory:

```
addr N+0: 0x12
addr N+1: 0x34 
addr N+2: 0x56 
addr N+3: 0x78
```

For most programming work you don't need to care. But sometimes it is could to know. For instance when debugging via memory dumps.

However, if you deal with (low level) communication protocols, it is important to know and care about whether your machine is big or little endian.

Big endian is the standard for most communication protocols, i.e. the most significant byte is transmitted first.

A function like OPs is typically used on a little endian machine when receiving a buffer from a network on a little endian machine (e.g. Intel).

The received buffer (byte buffer) would be b. If four 4 bytes at some offset (i) was to be interpreted as a uint32_t it would be necessary to convert from network order (big endian) to host order (litte endian in this case). The four bytes at offset i can be converted from network order to host using the function.

Most systems also provide functions like ntohl (net-to-host-long), htonl (host-to-net-long), etc. for this purpose. These will automatically handle the endianess of the host.

Example:

Assume you have received this buffer via some communication device using the "normal" big endian net format:

```
b[] = {0xa5, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x5a}
```

Also assume that you know the protocol dictates that this is to be interpreted as:

```
char, uint32_t, char
```

If you used brute force on a little endian machine like this:

```
uint32_t t = *((uint32_t*)&b[1]);
```

you would end up with the wrong value:

```
t = 0x78563412
```

But

```
uint32_t t;
GET_UINT32_BE(t,b,1);
```

will give the correct value:

```
t = 0x12345678
```